# Why did Heather Bram not get cured?

Tags: tv, the-dresden-files, werewolf

In **Hair of the Dog** they say that the death of the nineth werewolf from the same bloodline makes the damnation disappear. We see the FBI agent get cured when her boyfriend dies.

Why does Heather not get cured as well?

Answer (score 2):

> Kill nine, remove the sign.

The cure for lycanthropy in the *Dresden Files* TV series doesn't cure the entire bloodline, only the reluctant werewolf doing the deed.

Special Agent Kelly Raskin wanted to be rid of the lycanthropy curse, and so she was creating new werewolves in her own bloodline and then killing them. Completing the ritual wouldn't cure *other* werewolves in the bloodline, just Raskin.

---

Of note: the *Dresden Files* novel that most closely corresponds to this episode (*Fool Moon*) explores four different varieties of lupine theriomorphs. These are *not* explored in the TV episode:

- Werewolf: A person who transforms him- or herself into a wolf through magic. This is generally the only magic that individual knows. Alternatively, a magic-user may transform another person into a wolf, and this is very close to murder, and violates one of the Laws of Magic. There is no means to "cure" this variant, because it's either willful use of magic on oneself (which can also be reversed at-will), or else imposed transmogrification, leaving the subject effectively dead. (The "Alphas" are werewolves, and become Harry's allies in later novels.)
- Hexenwolf: A person uses a magical artifact or talisman to transform into a wolf. "Curing" this variant of werewolf is simply a matter of removing the talisman, although an individual may develop a dependence on it. (The two FBI agents in the book are both hexenwolves.)
- Lycanthrope: Not actually a theriomorph (shape-changer), lycanthropes are humans that act as a channel to a spirit of rage. They appear human, but often act like animals. There is no "cure," as it's simply the way the people are. Harry encounters a street gang of lycanthropes in the novel.
- Loup-Garou: loup-garous are cursed, and the curse follows the bloodline (and prevents the bloodline from dying out). A loup-garou is the only werewolf variant in the novel which transforms on the full moon and is particularly vulnerable to silver (in fact, it's their *only* real vulnerability, and that silver must be inherieted, to boot). While transformed, a loup-garou will attack and kill anything and anyone within sight. The loup-garou curse requires serious magical mojo along the lines of the faerie queens (Mab/Titania), and breaking it would be beyond Harry's power (that said, while resilient, a loup-garou isn't invulnerable). The character Harley MacFinn is a loup-garou, whose family line was cursed by Saint Patrick.

At the end of the novel, Harry speculates on the existence of a fifth type of lupine shapechanger: Jim Butcher leaves it up to the reader, but hints at the possibility that the character Tera West is a wolf that transforms into a human, rather than a human that transforms into a wolf. Tera West taught the Alphas the magic required to become werewolves. This "wolfwere" is canonized in the *Dresden Files* RPG.

Comment: If the FBI agents are hexenwolves (thus depending on a talisman), how is it that the guy gets transformed by being bitten? Or is this a difference between the novels and the TV Series?

Comment: @Envite - The TV show's werewolves have nothing to do with the book's types.  Also, the existence of wolfweres is confirmed in the RPG sourcebooks, which are canonical.

Comment: @Compro01, I don't have much experience with the RPG (tried to get in on a campaign on Roll20, but it fell through); I never knew that the supplemental material in it was considered canon! Now I want to go find myself my own copy and read through it.

Comment: @BrianS - You can obtain the books at [Evil Hat Productions](http://www.evilhat.com/store/index.php?main_page=index) in various formats (hardcopy, PDF, or a cheaper stripped down (most of the art removed) version in .mobi or .epub)